# Get first and last day of week in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am trying to get the first day and last day of a database column that lists the week numbers of the year. I am able to fetch all the weeks into a list but I would like to list it like first day and last day of month. For example: I have week of the year "39" and "40". I would like to display it in a listview like "24 sep - 30 oct" and "1 oct - 7 oct".

I use this query and SimpleCursorAdapter to display into a listview:

```
    String query = "SELECT _id, semana_ano, SUM(valor_uber) AS valor FROM uber_records GROUP BY semana_ano ORDER BY semana_ano";

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.get(Calendar.MONTH);

    String[] from = {"week_year", "value"};
    int[] to = {R.id.week,R.id.value};
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(ReportWeek.this,
            R.layout.report_week,
            cursor,from,to);

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
 void getStartEndOFWeek(int enterWeek, int enterYear){
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.clear();
        calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, enterWeek);
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, enterYear);

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM");
        Date startDate = calendar.getTime();
        String startDateInStr = formatter.format(startDate);

        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);
        Date enddate = calendar.getTime();
        String endDaString = formatter.format(enddate);
        String getDate = startDateInStr + " - " + endDaString;
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't work since it would have to loop through all records